# Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline) for Java / maven/ Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I just came into new wave for `Jenkinsfile`, that is now allows to do it as Declarative Pipeline.

What should be standard `Jenkinsfile` for maven project, e.g. Spring Boot?

Comment: What's your problem here?,
What you need to do in your jenkinsfile? 
Are you focusing on just build, or also test?

Comment: By pipeline they usually mean CD continuous delivery. Test is usually within maven build.
Or do you mean integration test, that should include deployment to test environment? For an example the more the better.

Answer (score 3):

This is my Jenkins File for my Maven Project. i.e., Spring Boot as per your requirement. Have a look.

```
node {
  try{
    stage 'checkout project'
    checkout scm

    stage 'check env'
    sh "mvn -v"
    sh "java -version"

    stage 'test'
    sh "mvn test"

    stage 'package'
    sh "mvn package"

    stage 'report'
    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])

    stage 'Artifact'
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true])

  }catch(e){
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is nice example for scripted pipeline, but not of declarative pipeline https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Answer (score 1):

Currently (Sep 2017) for declarative syntax these few links can help

- maven with docker https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/
- https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/
- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin
  that gives `withMaven(`

UPDATE 2021 The Pipeline Maven Integration
seems to be progressing a lot.
Recommend reading from GitHub page
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-maven-plugin
as Jenkins wiki has a bit corrupted view.

Comment: Is there a reference Jenkinsfile that we can refer to for spring boot maven project that creates an application docker image and pushes it to a private docker registry?